# Rails - how to save data to database with Delayed Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, delayed-job

I am authenticating users through Facebook and I would like to store person's friends in database. Because people can have up to 5000 friends on FB and I would like to save these 5000 people into our database, it will take a lot of time.

I was thinking about using Delayed Job for this purpose, but there is one thing - I found an example only how to send an email with Delayed job, but how to save data to database with Delayed Job?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have method `User#store_friends` that does the thing. All you need to do is call it with delayed job:

```
user.delay.store_friends
```

Comment: It seems to be death-simple, let me try it.